# Calling catch() on save() method on mongoose document object gives me an undefined error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Below code snippet uses mongoose `findById()` to get the document object and update values of some fields returned on that document. But the problem is it executes the code inside the `then()` block but response has a null value, and also it throws me "Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined", which I cannot understand why it happens.

```
Script.findById(scriptId)
  .then(script => {
    if (script) {
      const scriptId = script._id.toString();
      const demoUrl = `${scriptId}.mydomain.com`;
      if (true) {
        script.approved = true;
        script.demoUrl = demoUrl;
        script
          .save(response => {
            console.log(response); // this logs a null value
            res.json({
              message: "Script approved.",
              demoUrl: demoUrl
            });
          })
          .catch(error => { // throws me the error "Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined"
            next(error);
          });
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `.save` doesn't take a parameter and returns a promise, the code should look like this

```
Script.findById(scriptId)
  .then(script => {
    if (script) {
      const scriptId = script._id.toString();
      const demoUrl = `${scriptId}.mydomain.com`;
      if (true) {
        script.approved = true;
        script.demoUrl = demoUrl;
        script.save()
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response); // this logs a null value
            res.json({
              "message": "Script approved.",
              "demoUrl": demoUrl
            });
          })
          .catch(error => { // throws me the error "Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined"
            next(error);
          });
      }
    }
  });
```

Have a then after save to get the response and then do a catch.

Comment: you're right. silly me forgot to add then() block and I know this is totally a dumb question!

Comment: @yash no question is dumb. Please mark this as answer.